# Java why calendar afieldset is false?

Tags: java, calendar

I use java calendar. When I change date using calendar.set(...) I see in debugger

```
areFieldSet=false.
```

How can I make it to true?
Because when I ask date - I receive not correct value.
Thanks.

Comment: Please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: I suspect you've got a different problem which has nothing to do with this - if you can post a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem you're really having, we can address that... (It's easy to get calendar calculations wrong, and it would be much better to show us what you're doing than to guess at the cause.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally you don't need to care about that. But anyway, calling any method that needs fields to be set, for example `calendar.get(0)`, will make that field true.

Answer (score 2):

Calling an appropriate `get` method will force the fields to be recomputed - but why do you care? If you just use the public API, you shouldn't care about this field.

As an aside, you might want to look at the [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) library as a *far* superior date/time API for Java.

Answer (score 1):

The JavaDoc on that field:

> True if *fields[]* are in sync with the currently set time.
>   If false, then the next attempt to get the value of a field will
>   force a recomputation of all fields from the current value of
>   *time*.

Since this is an internal field, you shouldn't worry about that.